# Simple way to pause execution for a few seconds, that does not involve Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, asp.net

What's the best way in asp.net c# to achieve the following, that **does not** involve `Thread.Sleep()` ?

```
while (runCriteria)
{
 ...
    run some code to display something
 ...
 wait for x seconds
}
```

I've searched online and everything appears to use incredibly complex (at least to me) async timer events etc., which seems like overkill.

Comment: What's wrong with `Thread.Sleep()`? `Thread.Sleep` does not block any other thread, it only blocks the current thread which is the current request.

Comment: Can you provide some info as to *why* you prefer not to use `Thread.Sleep`? Or why you need to *wait* at all?

Answer (score 2):

If you're in .NET 4.5 asynchronous code, consider

```
await Task.Delay(delayTime);
```

[See MSDN docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Create some shared resource like mutex or semaphore or monitor etc. that will always be unreachable for your threads and acquire(wait for) it with the timeout.

Comment: There aren't multiple threads per page request.  There's only one.

Comment: The purpose of these tools is to synchronize access to shared resources for multiple threads.  If you don't have multiple threads, there's no reason to use them.

Comment: Sure, and the purpose of threadSleep is to sleep :) but the author of question is looking for an alternative way to wait. When using sync approach usually spinWait will be used internally, which is similar to @stepandohnal anwser.

Comment: These tools are potentially going to spinwait for just a little bit, in the case that the lock is released very quickly, but then it will move on to actually put the thread to sleep, making it virtually identical to `Thread.Sleep` if you know you'll be waiting for several seconds.  If anything, it'll be a bit worse, while still being very similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread.SpinWait`. It adds nop instructions, so there wont be a context switch.

Comment: This is potentially useful for waiting for very short periods of time.  On the order of a few microseconds.  Waiting for several full seconds is not something to be done with a spinwait.